# Better format to keep data in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

My question is quite simple.

I'm saving the data to local storage as string with `JSON.stringify(data_object)` and using `JSON.parse(loaded_data)` after load it back.

What is the best way to keep data on local storage? Save it in string format or as object? There are some difference is these approaches?

Thank you.

Comment: `localStorage` only stores strings. You have to JSON encode/decode an object to store it in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only items in [`localStorage` as strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage.setItem('testObject', {test: 'object'});
console.dir(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
```

You will see `"[object Object]"` because that is the *string representation* of the data you tried to store.

So your current method is correct.